# Xamarin.Forms: ERROR - 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Good Day. I'm creating a simple Xamarin.Forms (Portable) application that allows me to create Employee Records and display it in the UWP part of my program. It's working fine minutes ago but when I tried it again, It started not to work properly.

The application is actually running but the List of Employees that is supposed to be displayed on a ListView doesn't seem to appear. Instead, I get this messages on the Output Box.

[image]

I prefer not to show anymore codes because I think I don't have any error there. One more thing, all the back up program of this application that I have is not working anymore. It all displays the message in the image above.

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the `.Message` and `.InnerException` of the `HttpRequestException` that is thrown?

Comment: @SushiHangover what's that Sir? Sorry. Where can I find that?

Comment: try/catch the `HttpRequestException` and set a breakpoint on it...

Comment: Do not post error messages as images.  Take the time to post them as text.

Comment: @Jason noted Sir. Sorry.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista did find any solution for this.